# Replacing elements of a list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the original list with dictionaries inside it for 3 drinks and their corresponding prices and stock levels.

```
products = [
    {
        "name": "coke",
        "price": 3,
        "stock": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "bepis",
        "price": 2,
        "stock": 232
    },
    {
        "name": "fanta",
        "price": 2,
        "stock": 144
    }
[
```

If I had 3 lists such as these:

```
["mdew", "water", "tea", "tapwater"] # names
["3", "10", "3", "40"] # prices
["10", "10", "10"] # stock levels, tap water is out of stock so there are only 3 values here
```

As seen above there are 3 new lists but now there are 4 total drinks. The lists correspond to each other e.g mdew - 3 - 10, water 10 - 10, tea - 3 - 10, tapwater - 40 -  EMPTY.

How could I go about recreating the first list, replacing the values with the 3 lists? Sorry if this was poorly worded.

Thank you!

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: So the question is : how can I create a dictionnary based on those lists right? (and handling the fact that a key could have no value) ?

Comment: How do you know that the missing element is `tapwater`? In other words, what would the data look like if, say, `tea` was out of stock?

Answer (score 1):

You'd ordinarily use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#zip) to "zip up" multiple iterables to iterate over simultaneously:

```
for (name, price, stock) in zip(names, prices, stocks):
    print(f"{name=}, {price=}, {stock=}")
```

The output would be

```
name='mdew', price='3', stock='10'
name='water', price='10', stock='10'
name='tea', price='3', stock='10'
```

– notice the conspicuous lack of tap water.

Since one iterable is shorter than the others, you'll need [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

After that, generating a list of dicts is just a list comprehension away.

```
import itertools

names = ["mdew", "water", "tea", "tapwater"]
prices = ["3", "10", "3", "40"]
stocks = ["10", "10", "10"]

products = [
    {"name": name, "price": price, "stock": stock or 0}
    for (name, price, stock) in itertools.zip_longest(names, prices, stocks)
]

print(products)
```

The output is

```
[
  {'name': 'mdew', 'price': '3', 'stock': '10'},
  {'name': 'water', 'price': '10', 'stock': '10'},
  {'name': 'tea', 'price': '3', 'stock': '10'},
  {'name': 'tapwater', 'price': '40', 'stock': 0},
]
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to use `itertools` (for whichever reason), you can write something like `zip_longest` yourself (this is intentionally simplified to require `len()`able iterables):

```
def zip_longest_lists(*lists):
    max_len = max(len(l) for l in lists)
    for i in range(max_len):
        yield tuple((l[i] if i < len(l) else None) for l in lists)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Would there be any way to do this without the requirement of modules?

Comment: Of course you can write the equivalent of `zip_longest` yourself. `itertools` is a built-in module that's always available, though.

Comment: @electricmanh See my edit, please.

Comment: Exactly the help I was looking for. Thank you very much!